# Electrical light switches for 12 V DC

Tags: switches, ac-dc

I am converting a campervan at the moment and am now at the stage of choosing the light switches to use with my 12 V lights. I am not keen on the ones for caravans as they are not that great to look at. I have been told that any light switch will work with them but I am not sure if this is correct.

The light switches I want to use state Max. Voltage: 110V~250V AC 16 amps.

I have 12 V DC lights with max 18 W and 1.5 amps and another one for 12 V DC with max 16 W 3.2 amps.

Can anyone tell me if this switch would be ok to use?

[This is the type of switch I was thinking of](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001725844483.html?spm=a2g0s.8937460.0.0.6fdb2e0eNduVYA).

Comment: The switches aren’t specified to switch DC,however, due to the nature of the led circuits and lower currents they should work without a problem.  Get the switches without indicators as the indicators won’t work due to the much lower voltage being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AC rated switches are designed to used in a system where arcing is minimal due to the zero cross of the AC waveform. This leads to reduced damage to the contacts on the switch.

DC does not have this zero crossing and trying to handle the same current as the AC rating will lead to significantly lower lifespan and possible negative failure like failing closed.

If you look at switches that have both AC and DC ratings, the DC voltage for the same amperage is much lower due to this and some other issues.

But your situation is ideal. Your target application is significantly lower in both current and voltage. That means it is ***derated*** compared to the rated specs. Derating is the process of reducing the specs to meet a different goal.

By using 12V and 3 Amps, it is low enough that the consequences of arcing can be negligible. The lifespan of the switch should not be greatly impacted.

Granted you are using parts against their tested and rated use, so if it causes a fire, your insurance will not be happy if they find out. Or worse. Of course you are using foreign parts of questionable quality and sourcing as well, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The switch's specs do not mention the use of DC, so nobody can say for sure if it will do the job. I doubt that the built in indicators will light up. The switch is not made for your desired kind of operation. Usually the manufacturer of the switch tells you the rated current for DC and AC and that is the main specification besides the rated voltage.

Because of the low current it will likely work.